# Keras Concatenate outputs of Dense into a Matrix

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm trying to implement a Keras model with a quite complex structure (at least wrt what I'm used to) using the API.
The model should feature a single CNN to extract features from a sequence of frames (all the frames should essentially be parsed by the same CNN), and the outputs of the CNN should then be concatenated to form a matrix again.

Let's suppose the input frames are images 64x64 and the output of the CNN is a Dense(16)

```py
input_frame = tf.keras.Input(shape=(64, 64, 3))
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16,(4,4), activation='relu')(input_frame)
x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32,(4,4), activation='relu')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32,(4,4), activation='relu')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(16)(x)

features_out = [x for i in range(num_frames)]
```

I then try to concatenate the outputs with

```py
tcn_input = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=-1)(features_out)
```

In the summary I get

```
dense_27 (Dense)                (None, 16)           33296       flatten_13[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_10 (Concatenate)    (None, 240)          0           dense_27[0][0]                   
                                                                 dense_27[0][0]                   
                                                                 dense_27[0][0]                   
                                                                 dense_27[0][0]                   
                                                                 dense_27[0][0]                   
                                                                 dense_27[0][0]                   
                                                                 dense_27[0][0]                   
                                                                 dense_27[0][0]                   
                                                                 dense_27[0][0]                   
                                                                 dense_27[0][0]                   
                                                                 dense_27[0][0]                   
                                                                 dense_27[0][0]                   
                                                                 dense_27[0][0]                   
                                                                 dense_27[0][0]                   
                                                                 dense_27[0][0]                   
==================================================================================================
```

Which I believe is correct. In my case, though, I would rather a matrix, so I tried to do

```py
tcn_input = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=0)(features_out)
```

But changing the axis gives me this result

```
dense_31 (Dense)                (None, 16)           33296       flatten_17[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_14 (Concatenate)    (None, 16)           0           dense_31[0][0]                   
                                                                 dense_31[0][0]                   
                                                                 dense_31[0][0]                   
                                                                 dense_31[0][0]                   
                                                                 dense_31[0][0]                   
                                                                 dense_31[0][0]                   
                                                                 dense_31[0][0]                   
                                                                 dense_31[0][0]                   
                                                                 dense_31[0][0]                   
                                                                 dense_31[0][0]                   
                                                                 dense_31[0][0]                   
                                                                 dense_31[0][0]                   
                                                                 dense_31[0][0]                   
                                                                 dense_31[0][0]                   
                                                                 dense_31[0][0]                   
==================================================================================================
```

with output shape of 16, which I find confusing (I expected to have 16xnum_frames).
I believe I'm misunderstanding something in how the layers are connected but I could not figure it out.
Anyone can explain why it's giving the output I expected?

Comment: You're concatenating along the batch axis (axis=0). Before you put training data into the model, the batch size is unknown (i.e., None). None times and integer is None, which is why you are seeing (None, 16) as the output. If you put data into your model with a batch_size of B and set num_frames to N, your output will be of size (B*N, 16)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it's pointed out in the comments, you are concatenating along either feature or batch dimension, instead of concatenating on a new dimension. YOu can make the following change to get a [batch size, num_frames, 16] sized tensor.

```
input_frame = tf.keras.Input(shape=(64, 64, 3))
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16,(4,4), activation='relu')(input_frame)
x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32,(4,4), activation='relu')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32,(4,4), activation='relu')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(16)(x)

# Add a new dimension to x so that we can concatenate over that
features_out = [tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x[:, tf.newaxis, :])(x) for i in range(num_frames)]

# We concatenate over the new dimension
tcn_input = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=-2)(features_out)

model = tf.keras.models.Model(input_frame, tcn_input)
```